# ffmpeg find 1st frame where the video starts

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frame, detection

My colleague had several video files, which were resized and re-encoded with libx264. Then the video files were split into segments with ffmpeg as well - without reencoding them. Unfortunately. Is far as I understand, the video files were split not at keyframes. Now the videos start with playing audio immediately, and a video frame, which act as a picture, are shown without any change for about 2-4 secs, then (and only then) the video starts to play as well.

My goal is to modify the video segments to start playing the video immediately - the audio part before the 1st keyframe can be dropped out. The problem is - I don't know where the 1st keyframe is, where the video start playing. It seems it differs for every video now.

I have several videos, so I need to write a script to do this. Is there any tool or something which can detect the index of the 1st frame where the video really starts? Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: What's the container - MP4?

Comment: Looks like a very similar questions was answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/554620/how-to-get-time-stamp-of-closest-keyframe-before-a-given-timestamp-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: The container is .mkv.

Comment: It looks the ffprobe information can be useful. I wonder if there is a command line option to tell ffprobe prints only the 1st keyframe information, not all (keeps too long). Any idea?